# Trello- referring the client.js file and not able to call function on type"Success" in Trello.authorize API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, trello

I am following the sample mentioned @ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNesx/)

When the same code i copied in separate HTML,Javascript and CSS then the same code does not work.

HTML:

```
              <head>             

       <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=apllication key"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />                        
        <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                </script> -->

       </head>
           <body>

  <div id="loggedout">
      <a id="connectLink" href="#">Connect To Trello</a>
 </div>

  <div id="loggedin">
   <div id="header">
    Logged in to as <span id="fullName"></span> 
    <a id="disconnect" href="#">Log Out</a>
   </div>

   <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
```

Script.js content:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police investigation!');
         console.log("alert printed");



 $("#connectLink")
   .click(function(){
      Trello.authorize({
                type:"popup",
               name: "from link",
                success: function() {
               alert("in success");
        },
               error:function() {
               alert("in error");
              }
              })
          });
```

});

on success , i want to write my function but it does not seem to be calling it. Any thing that I am missing.

Comment: Is the popup showing?  Do you go through the giving access steps?

Comment: Yes pop appearing, then the function should be called if i say allow which is not happening. I followed the steps mentioned in the trello api documentaion ( refered the client.js file and provide the application key.

Comment: Well, what is happening?  Is there anything in the console?  Have you tried any debugging?

Comment: Yes i tried debugging but it is not helping. In the console if i try to print any text that also is not coming.

How come the same code is woking in JSfiddle site but not separately in my project.

Comment: do you have a project which you could share with in zipped format which is working with Trello API, then that will be great. My email id is sourabhpandey05@gmail.com

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and figured out that was because I'm trying to authorize from a `file://` URL.

Not understanding exactly why but the authorize page doesn't redirect or close popup in that case.

I simply solved the issue by serving my page on localhost with a webserver (I used nodejs in my case with `serve-static` module).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the browser you are testing this in is IE.

I had experienced a similar problem with the API where the popup window doesn't call the OnSuccess function, but works fine in jsFiddle, which seems to be the problem you are having here.

My solution was to change the type to be "redirect" so that it asks for permission in the same window.
This method works fine in IE with the separate files.

```
 $("#connectLink").click(function() {
   Trello.authorize({
     type:"redirect",
     name: "from link",
     success: function() {
       alert("in success");
      },
      error:function() {
        alert("in error");
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: still the same issue - getting below error in firefox:

Corrupted Content Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

and in chrome - nothing happens on click on allow..:(